# How to set Hours,minutes,seconds to Date which is in GMT

Tags: javascript, date

I have Date Object ,I wanted to clear HOUR,MINUTE and SECONDS from My Date.Please help me how to do it in Javascript. Am i doing wrong ?

```
var date = Date("Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:30:00 GMT");
      date.setHours(0);
      date.setMinutes(0);
      date.setSeconds(0);
```

Expected result is

```
Fri, 26 Sep 2014 00:00:00 GMT
```

How Do I achieve ?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use this:

```
// Like Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:30:00 GMT
var today = new Date();

var myToday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
```

Recreate the Date object with constructor using the actual date.

Comment: `today.getDate();` @Blader Please correct in answer

Comment: I've used this code to get set an object that holds tomorrow's date at midnight - var tomorrow_midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0); Just wanted to share this with the world... :)

Comment: Answer below of using theDate.setHours(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) would be better.

Comment: that only works if your in GMT time zone

Answer (score 133):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) the `setHours` function actually takes additional optional parameters to set both minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Hence we may simply write

```
// dateString is for example "Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:30:00 GMT"
function getFormattedDate(dateString) {
   var date = new Date(dateString);
   date.setHours(0, 0, 0);   // Set hours, minutes and seconds
   return date.toString();
}
```

Comment: to set milliseconds, you should write `date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` : four zeros

Answer (score 10):

To parse the date into JavaScript simply use

```
var date = new Date("Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:30:00 GMT”);
```

And then set Hours, Minutes and seconds to 0 with the following lines

```
date.setHours(0);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
```

`date.toString()` now returns your desired date

Comment: So why not set it like so - var date = new Date("Fri, 26 Sep 2014 00:00:00 GMT”), and save the extra unneeded code?...

Comment: @TheCuBeMan I'd assume it's because you'd have to do some string manipulation. Seems much easier to just do the date.setHours() part, IMO.