# How to get Last Day data using Date Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am working to filter data. Filter will be Last Day, Last Week, Last Month.

My code is :

For Last Week :

```
dateUntil = Date.now();
dateSince = date.setDate(date.getDate()-7)
```

Last Month :

```
dateUntil = Date.now();
dateSince = date.setDate(date.getDate()-30)
```

In Last Day filter I am using :

```
dateUntil = Date.now();
dateSince = date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
```

In last dates it shows, data from this time to yesterday this time. But I want to set Last dates 12.00 am to 11.59pm.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You have so many `DateObject` methods like `setMinutes/setHours/setSeconds` etc...

Comment: You can do `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` This will clear time part

Comment: May be — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663538/how-to-set-hours-minutes-seconds-to-date-which-is-in-gmt

Comment: [*Date.now*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.now) does not return a Date object. Perhaps you want `dateUntil = new Date()`.

Comment: If you want one month ago, use `date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1)`, however you **must** check the date since 31 July minus one month gives 31 June, which rolls over to 1 July (same result if you just subtract 30 days). The effect is worse for March.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below it worked for me :

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
alert(d);
```

Comment: Can you give me example what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you

```
var datenow = new Date().toDateString();
var dateUntil = new Date(datenow);
var dateSince = new Date(datenow);
dateSince.setDate(dateUntil.getDate()-1);
```