# Calculating difference between hours

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, date-fns

I've searched SO and have found solutions to this, but they don't use date-fns or just don't work, since they're calculating days and I'm only focused on hours in the same day.

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates, or more specifically, between hours in the same day so that I can get when someone clocked in and clocked out and calculate the amount of hours they worked for that day.

I'm using date-fns

If I run `console.log(this.myForm.value.startTime)` I get `14:00`.

If I run `console.log(this.myForm.value.endTime)` I get `16:00`.

Here's my function to calculate the hours.

```
updateHours() {
    var end = dateFns.format(new Date(this.myForm.value.endTime, 'HH:mm'));
    var start = dateFns.format(new Date(this.myForm.value.startTime, 'HH:mm'));
    var result = dateFns.differenceInMinutes(
        new Date(end),
        new Date(start)
    )
    console.log(result);
}
```

The value of `result` is always `NaN`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an incorrect parsing going on, since you only want to get the difference in `minutes` it would be easier to follow this approach.

The value set to `end` and `start` variables were undefined in the original code.

In the below snippet I create a new date, set the hours and minutes using the date method `.setHours()`.

```
date.setHours(0, 0, 0);   // Set hours, minutes and seconds
```

```js
var start_time = "14:00";
var end_time = "16:00";

function updateHours() {
  var current = new Date();
  var start = current.setHours(start_time.split(":")[0], start_time.split(":")[1], 0);
  var end = current.setHours(end_time.split(":")[0], end_time.split(":")[1], 0);
  console.log(start, end)
  var result = dateFns.differenceInMinutes(
    end,
    start
  )
  console.log(result);
}
updateHours();
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

**References:**

1. [Set hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663538/how-to-set-hours-minutes-seconds-to-date-which-is-in-gmt)

Comment: works great until I get the value from my form `this.myForm.value.startTime`, then it returns `NaN`. I even tried `this.myForm.value.startTime as string` with no luck.

Comment: @timgavin Why not just do `this.myForm.value.startTime = this.myForm.value.startTime | "00:00"`, so that the falsy values are overriden by default value!

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks :)

Comment: @NarenMurali it does not work when var start_time = "20:00";
var end_time = "12:00";. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really easy if you have two `Date` objects, to get the difference substracting `Date.prototype.getTime` (so don't format with dateFns yet)

```
var minutes = Math.abs(start.getTime() - end.getTime()) / 60000 // display in minutes
```

You can also round it, `Math.round(minutes)`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This method: `var end = new Date(this.myForm.value.endTime)` gives me `NaN`, and this method: `var start = this.myForm.value.startTime;` gives me this: `ERROR TypeError: start.getTime is not a function`.