# How to set time to always: 00:00:00?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
const startDate =  new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').replace(/:/,'-');
```

But it gives the current time. But the time has always  to be set tot: 00:00:00

So what I have to change? Thank you

Comment: You could use [`setHours(0,0,0,0);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

Comment: Yes, oke, but where? I cant do startData.setHours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Hours,minutes,seconds to Date which is in GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663538/how-to-set-hours-minutes-seconds-to-date-which-is-in-gmt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var event = new Date();
event.setHours(1,0,0,0);
const startDate =  event.toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').replace(/:/,'-');
```

Comment: Please don't just post code also add some explanation about your solution

Comment: Thank you!! very nice

Answer (score 2):

```
const event = new Date();
event.setHours(0,0,0);

console.log(event);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwmn0ges/

Comment: easier to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/25663625/3163418

Comment: Yes, oke, But I cant do this: statDate.setHours() in my example

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to keep the format in your `const` startDate but set the time to the beginning of the day. Why not try this?

```js
function display(){
    const startDate =  new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '').replace(/:/,'-');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = startDate.split(' ')[0] + " 00:00:00";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="display()">Today's data with start time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```