# Unable to set the time to 00:00:00:00 using setHours() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to set time to 00:00:00:00 . But setInterval() stopped working.

```js
 document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function () {
       
        setInterval(function () {
            let myDate = new Date();
            myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0);
            let a = myDate.getHours();
        let b = myDate.getMinutes();
        let c = myDate.getSeconds();
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = `${a}:${b}:${c}`;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<h2 id="counter"></h2>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Hours,minutes,seconds to Date which is in GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663538/how-to-set-hours-minutes-seconds-to-date-which-is-in-gmt)

Comment: It might help reading about what `setHours` *does* exactly: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`, you should call `let myDate = new Date(0)`; but what you really need to do is subtract the current time from the time when the timer started.

If you want to make this reusable, wrap it in a class. Also, you need to take into account the stoppage time when pausing.

Here is an example of decoupling the time, task, and UI. Each stopwatch is independent of one another.

**Update:** Added some more pizazz with some themes.

```js
/**
 * The Stopwatch class is based on:
 * https://olinations.medium.com/an-accurate-vanilla-js-stopwatch-script-56ceb5c6f45b
 */
class Stopwatch {
  constructor(task, updateRate = 10) {
    this.startTime = 0;
    this.updatedTime = 0;
    this.difference = 0;
    this.savedTime = 0;
    this.paused = false;
    this.running = false;
    this.tInterval = null;
    this.task = task;
    this.updateRate = updateRate;
  }
  update() {
    this.updatedTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (this.savedTime) {
      this.difference = (this.updatedTime - this.startTime) + this.savedTime;
    } else {
      this.difference =  this.updatedTime - this.startTime;
    }
    this.task(this.difference);
  }
  start() {
    if (!this.running) {
      this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
      this.tInterval = setInterval(() => this.update(), this.updateRate);
      this.paused = false;
      this.running = true;
    }
  }
  pause() {
    if (!this.difference) {
      // If timer never started, disallow pause button
    } else if (!this.paused) {
      clearInterval(this.tInterval);
      this.savedTime = this.difference;
      this.paused = true;
      this.running = false;
    } else {
      // this.start(); // Optional if Start/Pause is toggleable
    }
  }
  reset() {
    clearInterval(this.tInterval);
    this.tInterval = null;
    this.savedTime = 0;
    this.difference = 0;
    this.paused = false;
    this.running = false;
    this.task(this.difference);
  }
}

const formatTime = (ms) => {
  let
    hrs = Math.floor(ms / 36e5),
    min = Math.floor((ms - (hrs * 36e5)) / 6e4),
    sec = Math.floor((ms - (hrs * 36e5) - (min * 6e4)) / 1e3),
    mil = Math.floor((ms - (hrs * 36e5) - (min * 6e4) - (sec * 1e3)));
 
  hrs = `${hrs}`.padStart(2, '0');
  min = `${min}`.padStart(2, '0');
  sec = `${sec}`.padStart(2, '0');
  mil = `${mil}`.padStart(3, '0');

  return `${hrs}:${min}:${sec}.${mil}`;
}

// Link an internal stopwatch to a UI component.
const LinkStopwatchUI = (stopwatchEl) => {
  const
    displayEl = stopwatchEl.querySelector('.display'),
    startBtn  = stopwatchEl.querySelector('.start-btn'),
    pauseBtn  = stopwatchEl.querySelector('.pause-btn'),
    resetBtn  = stopwatchEl.querySelector('.reset-btn');

  const task = timeDiff => { displayEl.innerHTML = formatTime(timeDiff) };
  const stopwatch = new Stopwatch(task);

  stopwatch.reset();

  startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => stopwatch.start());
  pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => stopwatch.pause());
  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => stopwatch.reset());
}

document.querySelectorAll('.stopwatch').forEach(LinkStopwatchUI);
```

```css
:root {
  --sw-bg: #444;
  --sw-fg: #0F7;
  --sw-bc: #666;
  --sw-display-bg: #222;
  --sw-display-bc: #000;
  --sw-btn-bg: #555;
  --sw-btn-fg: #EEE;
  --sw-btn-bc: #666;
  --sw-btn-hover-bg: #777;
  --sw-btn-hover-fg: #FFF;
}

.stopwatch[data-theme="light"] {
  --sw-bg: #EEE;
  --sw-fg: #06D;
  --sw-bc: #666;
  --sw-display-bg: #CCC;
  --sw-display-bc: #AAA;
  --sw-btn-bg: #E7E7E7;
  --sw-btn-fg: #111;
  --sw-btn-bc: #AAA;
  --sw-btn-hover-bg: #FFF;
  --sw-btn-hover-fg: #000;
}

/* https://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/52138 */
.stopwatch[data-theme="calm"] {
  --sw-bg: #F5F0EC;
  --sw-fg: #152C43;
  --sw-bc: #72808E;
  --sw-display-bg: #BDDAC8;
  --sw-display-bc: #DED0C2;
  --sw-btn-bg: #DED0C2;
  --sw-btn-fg: #152C43;
  --sw-btn-bc: #72808E;
  --sw-btn-hover-bg: #BDDAC8;
  --sw-btn-hover-fg: #152C43;
}


html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;
}

.stopwatch {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-column-gap: 0.33em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  color: var(--sw-fg);
  background: var(--sw-bg);
  border: thin solid var(--sw-bc);
}

.stopwatch button {
  background: var(--sw-btn-bg);
  color: var(--sw-btn-fg);
  border: thin solid var(--sw-btn-bc);
}

.stopwatch button:hover {
  background: var(--sw-btn-hover-bg);
  color: var(--sw-btn-hover-fg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stopwatch .display {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: right;
  background: var(--sw-display-bg);
  border: thin solid var(--sw-display-bc);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.667em;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

.stopwatch .start-btn {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.stopwatch .stop-btn {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.stopwatch .reset-btn {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="stopwatch">
  <div class="display"></div>
  <button class="start-btn">Start</button>
  <button class="pause-btn">Pause</button>
  <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</div>

<div class="stopwatch" data-theme="light">
  <div class="display"></div>
  <button class="start-btn">Start</button>
  <button class="pause-btn">Pause</button>
  <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</div>

<div class="stopwatch" data-theme="calm">
  <div class="display"></div>
  <button class="start-btn">Start</button>
  <button class="pause-btn">Pause</button>
  <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at MDN's [documentation for `setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), you'll see that it:

> ...returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

`myDate` will have the updated date/time, but `myTime` is just that milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value.

If you want the string `"00:00:00:00"`, you'll have to create that yourself (although in your example, it would just be a literal, since none of it changes). It's not clear to me what the final `:00` is supposed to be (it's usually `.000` for milliseconds), but you can get the various parts of the date using `getHours`, `getMinutes`, etc., and build the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

this is because is returning a timestamp.

Here you can find the documentation where this is explained.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Here you can find a good example of how to convert timestamp to readable date

[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)