# moment() Get todays date with midnight

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to query the database with all records which are starting from today and greater than midnight.

```
var dateTime = moment().toDate();
```

gives me the current date and time. But is there any way to set the midnight of today?

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Tried the above but still it give me

```
2021-09-11T18:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: Why do you need this on the JS side? Why not query with `current_date`, or whatever equivalent your RDBMS uses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Hours,minutes,seconds to Date which is in GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663538/how-to-set-hours-minutes-seconds-to-date-which-is-in-gmt)

Comment: @Mureinik am using PosgresSQL. never done that before. any direction you can point me towards.

Comment: @HarshaMV something down the lines of `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_timestamp_column::date = CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: @Mureinik interesting. let me try this out. learnt something new. thanks.

Comment: `new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))` creates a date for local midnight at the start of the day, the timestamp `2021-09-11T18:30:00.000Z` is the UTC equivalent if your local offset is +5:30..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about

```
moment().startOf('day').toString();
```

```js
var now = moment().startOf('day').toString();
console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That produces an identical result to `new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toString()`.

Comment: See docs: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/03-start-of/